# How to make a sound file play continuously throughout the website?

Tags: html, css, audio

As opposed to playing on one page only, then reseting or going away when switching to another page. Is there any way to do with that with html/css?

Comment: You can use Jquery mobile multi-ipage template so you have the whole site in one html page. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/pages/ -- this will be your best bet. you will need to use  a plugin to  play the music instead of using html audio api audio tag because when you change a page to go to another it will stop -- https://github.com/IonDen/ion.sound

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in HTML5:

```
<audio src="audio-path.mp3" controls autoplay loop>
<p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>
</audio>
```

BUT, if your page has the file refresh every open link, it is useless to you.

You need to adapt your javascript to use the history.pushState for no more refresh the page.

Comment: Yeah my page does refresh every open link

Comment: You can fix this using history.pushState in javascript/html5